# How to run object detection in web application

Tags: php, server, web-applications, object-detection, yolo

I have finished an object detection project and I want to make a demo of it with a web application. I use YOLOv3 on Darknet for training. I intend to get the weights that I got from the training and use it in the web app. I decided to allow the user to upload an image, then take that image through a Python script, which will load my trained weights and do the detection. I decided to use PHP for the server-side and test everything on the localhost first.

I am totally new to web application and I don't know if I decided right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that..here are headlines to get you started

```
>First create the image upload form
>PHP script to first move the image to a folder accessible to .py for processing
then execute the .py script
>Save the result of the processing to a log (.json works best with php)
>Decode the .json with PHP
>if you need to do calculations with PHP, do so
>Lastly give the user the results they expect to get
```